# Codeigniter dynamic insert

Tags: database, codeigniter, dynamic, insert

I am new to CodeIgniter. I've already created the required program, but I want to make it smaller and more effective. I have a database with 10+ tables, where I just insert/update into almost the same rows (+/- 2 rows).

I would like to make a controller which inserts all the incoming data to the url specified table. Like: insert/news -> inserting data into news table, and all the [input] name's are equal to the table's column name.

So I just submit my form at url: insert/news where I have [input name="content"] and it automatically inserts into news table and content row.

Is it a good approach, or I should make separately 10+ models with create functions?

Thanks, and sorry for my newbie question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with that approach, and it's good if it fits your needs.

Use

```
 $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(x);
```

to get the table name.
Validate the data:

```
$this->input->post(...);
```

And for even more effective app make those controllers calls as [AJAX requests](http://runnable.com/UXczcazDrMMiAAGl/how-to-do-ajax-in-codeigniter-for-php).

Comment: Thank you, I could manage to understand the 1st part, 

`$array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(2);
return $this->db->insert($array['create'], $data);`

but how can I make my model understand dynamicly the posted content?

So I have to make this party dynamic:
`$data = array(
  'value1' => $this->input->post('value1'),
  'value2' => $this->input->post('value2),
  'valueN' => $this->input->post('valueN),
);`

Comment: $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); will fetch all $_POST data in one array, use that.